# Extracting Z (Elevation in meters) value any any point of a 3D Building file in 3D Tiles format using RayCasting on iTowns based on Three.js

Tags: three.js, gis, raycasting, cesiumjs, perspectivecamera

I have loaded a 3D building mesh file in 3D Tiles (Cesium 3D Tiles) format on iTowns (http://www.itowns-project.org/). When I click on any point of the building, I am getting the longitude and latitude (X and Y). But, I also want to get the height (Z) of the particular point of the building on which I am clicking. I am trying to do three.js Raycasting (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) for extracting the Z value when I click any point on the building.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var THREE = itowns.THREE; 
        var long_rad = -1.31968;  
        var lat_rad = 0.698874;  

        // Longitude and Latitude from tileset.json
        var long_deg = THREE.Math.radToDeg( long_rad ); 
        var lat_deg = THREE.Math.radToDeg( lat_rad ); 
        
        var placement = {
            coord: new itowns.Coordinates('EPSG:4326', long_deg, lat_deg, 0),  
            range: 2000
        }

        var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('viewerDiv');
        var view = new itowns.GlobeView(viewerDiv, placement); 
        view.camera.camera3D.near = 5;
        setupLoadingScreen(viewerDiv, view);
        var menuGlobe = new GuiTools('menuDiv', view, 300);

        itowns.Fetcher.json('./layers/JSONLayers/OPENSM.json').then(function _(config) {
            config.source = new itowns.TMSSource(config.source);
            var layer = new itowns.ColorLayer('Ortho', config);
            view.addLayer(layer).then(menuGlobe.addLayerGUI.bind(menuGlobe));
        });

        var $3dTilesLayerDiscreteLOD = new itowns.C3DTilesLayer('3d-tiles-discrete-lod', {
            name: 'DiscreteLOD',
            sseThreshold: 0.05,
            source: new itowns.C3DTilesSource({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/Data/Cesium3DTiles/Tilesets/Tileset/tileset.json',   
            }),
        }, view);

        itowns.View.prototype.addLayer.call(view, $3dTilesLayerDiscreteLOD);

        var $3dTilesLayerRequestVolume = new itowns.C3DTilesLayer('3d-tiles-request-volume', {
            name: 'RequestVolume',
            source: new itowns.C3DTilesSource({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/Data/Cesium3DTiles/Tilesets/TilesetWithViewerRequestVolume/tileset.json',
            }),
            sseThreshold: 1,
        }, view);

        var pickingArgs = {};
        pickingArgs.htmlDiv = document.getElementById('featureInfo');
        pickingArgs.view = view;
        pickingArgs.layer = $3dTilesLayerRequestVolume; 

        itowns.View.prototype.addLayer.call(view,
            $3dTilesLayerRequestVolume).then(function _() {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove',
                    (event) => fillHTMLWithPickingInfo(event, pickingArgs),false);
                    //(event) => picking(event, pickingArgs.htmlDiv, pickingArgs.view, pickingArgs.layer), false);
            });

        var d = new debug.Debug(view, menuGlobe.gui);
        debug.createTileDebugUI(menuGlobe.gui, view, view.tileLayer, d);
        debug.create3dTilesDebugUI(menuGlobe.gui, view, $3dTilesLayerDiscreteLOD, d);
        debug.create3dTilesDebugUI(menuGlobe.gui, view, $3dTilesLayerRequestVolume, d);
        d.zoom = function() {
            view.camera.camera3D.position.set(long_rad, lat_rad, 0); 
            view.notifyChange(view.camera.camera3D);
        }
        menuGlobe.gui.add(d, 'zoom').name('Go to point cloud');  

        function mouseclick_actions() {
            var cameraTargetPosition = view.controls.getLookAtCoordinate();  
            viewerDiv.addEventListener("click", event => {  

                var a = view.controls.pickGeoPosition(view.eventToViewCoords(event));
                cameraTargetPosition['x'] = a["x"];  
                cameraTargetPosition['y'] = a["y"];   
            
                console.log('a = ', a);    

                event_norm_coord = view.eventToNormalizedCoords(event);  
                console.log("event_norm_coord = ", event_norm_coord);    

                //Raycasting process
                let rayCast = new THREE.Raycaster();     
                rayCast.setFromCamera(event_norm_coord, view.camera.camera3D);     

                console.log("rayCast = ", rayCast);  
                console.log("rayCast.ray = ", rayCast.ray); 
                console.log("rayCast.ray.origin = ", rayCast.ray.origin); 

                o = createSphere(rayCast.ray.at(100));    
                console.log("o = ", o);    

                dist = rayCast.ray.distanceSqToPoint(rayCast.ray.origin); 
                console.log("dist = ", dist);                     
            });
        }

        // Listen for globe full initialisation event
        view.addEventListener(itowns.GLOBE_VIEW_EVENTS.GLOBE_INITIALIZED, function globeInitialized() {
            mouseclick_actions();
        });

        let createSphere = function(pos) {
            const RADIUS = 5;   
            console.log("pos = ", pos); 
            let material_mesh = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0X4a57fa, shininess: 100, side: THREE.DoubleSide});   
            let geometry_mesh = new THREE.SphereGeometry(RADIUS, 30, 30);  
            let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_mesh, material_mesh);   
            sphere.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);    
            view.scene.add(sphere);     
        }
    </script>
```

console.log() outputs are:-

```
a =  Coordinates {isCoordinates: true, crs: "EPSG:4326", x: -75.61200231318375, y: 40.041814443380126, z: -0.13751138653606176, …}crs: "EPSG:4326"isCoordinates: truex: -75.61200231318375y: 40.041814443380126z: -0.13751138653606176_normal: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}_normalNeedsUpdate: truealtitude: (...)geodesicNormal: (...)latitude: (...)longitude: (...)__proto__: Object    

event_norm_coord =  Vector2 {x: 0.1967741935483871, y: -0.20081549439347612}x: 0.9887096774193549y: -0.5372069317023445height: -0.5372069317023445width: 0.9887096774193549__proto__: Objectadd: ƒ ( v, w )addScalar: ƒ ( s )addScaledVector: ƒ ( v, s )addVectors: ƒ ( a, b )angle: ƒ ()applyMatrix3: ƒ ( m )ceil: ƒ ()clamp: ƒ ( min, max )clampLength: ƒ ( min, max )clampScalar: ƒ ( minVal, maxVal )clone: ƒ ()copy: ƒ ( v )cross: ƒ ( v )distanceTo: ƒ ( v )distanceToManhattan: ƒ ( v )distanceToSquared: ƒ ( v )divide: ƒ ( v )divideScalar: ƒ ( scalar )dot: ƒ ( v )equals: ƒ ( v )floor: ƒ ()fromArray: ƒ ( array, offset )fromAttribute: ƒ ( attribute, index, offset )fromBufferAttribute: ƒ ( attribute, index, offset )getComponent: ƒ ( index )isVector2: truelength: ƒ ()lengthManhattan: ƒ ()lengthSq: ƒ ()lerp: ƒ ( v, alpha )lerpVectors: ƒ ( v1, v2, alpha )manhattanDistanceTo: ƒ ( v )manhattanLength: ƒ ()max: ƒ ( v )min: ƒ ( v )multiply: ƒ ( v )multiplyScalar: ƒ ( scalar )negate: ƒ ()normalize: ƒ ()random: ƒ ()rotateAround: ƒ ( center, angle )round: ƒ ()roundToZero: ƒ ()set: ƒ ( x, y )setComponent: ƒ ( index, value )setLength: ƒ ( length )setScalar: ƒ ( scalar )setX: ƒ ( x )setY: ƒ ( y )sub: ƒ ( v, w )subScalar: ƒ ( s )subVectors: ƒ ( a, b )toArray: ƒ ( array, offset )constructor: ƒ Vector2( x, y )height: (...)width: (...)get height: ƒ ()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: "get"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: three.module.js?5a89:619[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]set height: ƒ ( value )get width: ƒ ()set width: ƒ ( value )__proto__: Object      

rayCast =  Raycaster {ray: Ray, near: 0, far: Infinity, camera: PerspectiveCamera, layers: Layers, …}camera: PerspectiveCamera {uuid: "8CE2A7FF-28F4-4CBD-9B56-316C193EF7DC", name: "", type: "PerspectiveCamera", parent: null, children: Array(0), …}far: Infinitylayers: Layers {mask: 1}near: 0params: LOD: {}Line: {threshold: 1}threshold: 1__proto__: ObjectMesh: {}Points: {threshold: 1}Sprite: {}PointCloud: (...)get PointCloud: ƒ ()__proto__: Objectray: Raydirection: Vector3x: -0.07883103464612029y: 0.7740105989626435z: 0.6282461783967429__proto__: Objectorigin: Vector3 {x: 1215046.3152875216, y: -4736495.215309124, z: 4081428.7261119974}__proto__: ObjectlinePrecision: (...)__proto__: Object    

rayCast.ray =  Ray {origin: Vector3, direction: Vector3}direction: Vector3x: -0.07883103464612029y: 0.7740105989626435z: 0.6282461783967429__proto__: Objectorigin: Vector3x: 1215046.3152875216y: -4736495.215309124z: 4081428.7261119974__proto__: Object__proto__: Object  


rayCast.ray.origin =  Vector3 {x: 1215046.3152875216, y: -4736495.215309124, z: 4081428.7261119974}x: 1215046.3152875216y: -4736495.215309124z: 4081428.7261119974__proto__: Objectadd: ƒ ( v, w )addScalar: ƒ ( s )addScaledVector: ƒ ( v, s )addVectors: ƒ ( a, b )angleTo: ƒ ( v )applyAxisAngle: ƒ ( axis, angle )applyEuler: ƒ ( euler )applyMatrix3: ƒ ( m )applyMatrix4: ƒ ( m )applyNormalMatrix: ƒ ( m )applyProjection: ƒ ( m )applyQuaternion: ƒ ( q )ceil: ƒ ()clamp: ƒ ( min, max )clampLength: ƒ ( min, max )clampScalar: ƒ ( minVal, maxVal )clone: ƒ ()copy: ƒ ( v )cross: ƒ ( v, w )crossVectors: ƒ ( a, b )distanceTo: ƒ ( v )distanceToManhattan: ƒ ( v )arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "distanceToManhattan"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: three.module.js?5a89:49649[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]distanceToSquared: ƒ ( v )divide: ƒ ( v )divideScalar: ƒ ( scalar )dot: ƒ ( v )equals: ƒ ( v )floor: ƒ ()fromArray: ƒ ( array, offset )fromAttribute: ƒ ( attribute, index, offset )fromBufferAttribute: ƒ ( attribute, index, offset )getColumnFromMatrix: ƒ ( index, matrix )getComponent: ƒ ( index )getPositionFromMatrix: ƒ ( m )getScaleFromMatrix: ƒ ( m )isVector3: truelength: ƒ ()lengthManhattan: ƒ ()lengthSq: ƒ ()lerp: ƒ ( v, alpha )lerpVectors: ƒ ( v1, v2, alpha )manhattanDistanceTo: ƒ ( v )manhattanLength: ƒ ()max: ƒ ( v )min: ƒ ( v )multiply: ƒ ( v, w )multiplyScalar: ƒ ( scalar )multiplyVectors: ƒ ( a, b )negate: ƒ ()normalize: ƒ ()project: ƒ ( camera )projectOnPlane: ƒ ( planeNormal )projectOnVector: ƒ ( v )random: ƒ ()reflect: ƒ ( normal )round: ƒ ()roundToZero: ƒ ()set: ƒ ( x, y, z )setComponent: ƒ ( index, value )setEulerFromQuaternion: ƒ ()setEulerFromRotationMatrix: ƒ ()setFromCylindrical: ƒ ( c )setFromCylindricalCoords: ƒ ( radius, theta, y )setFromMatrix3Column: ƒ ( m, index )setFromMatrixColumn: ƒ ( m, index )setFromMatrixPosition: ƒ ( m )setFromMatrixScale: ƒ ( m )setFromSpherical: ƒ ( s )setFromSphericalCoords: ƒ ( radius, phi, theta )setLength: ƒ ( length )setScalar: ƒ ( scalar )setX: ƒ ( x )setY: ƒ ( y )setZ: ƒ ( z )sub: ƒ ( v, w )subScalar: ƒ ( s )subVectors: ƒ ( a, b )toArray: ƒ ( array, offset )transformDirection: ƒ ( m )unproject: ƒ ( camera )constructor: ƒ Vector3( x, y, z )__proto__: Object   


pos =  Vector3 {x: 1215038.432184057, y: -4736417.814249228, z: 4081491.5507298373}x: 1215038.432184057y: -4736417.814249228z: 4081491.5507298373__proto__: Object     

o =  undefined    
dist =  0
```

When I click on any point on the 3D Tiles file, I have to display X, Y and Z. I am getting X and Y (in this case, x: -75.61200231318375 and y: 40.041814443380126. But, I am getting z: -0.13751138653606176. Instead, what I want is to display the height of building from bottom to the particular point. For example, if I click on the the middle point of a building (example, middle point of 2nd floor out of 3 floors), then I have to get z=5 m if total height of building=10 m.

How can I solve this issue of extracting height value in units of meters?